# Understanding normalization tables in Django's ORM

Tags: python, django, orm, normalization

I'm trying to learn Django from a background of coding the database schema directly myself. I want to understand how I should be effectively using the database abstraction tools to normalize.

As a contrived example, let's say I have a conversation that can ask questions on 3 subjects, and each question is complicated enough to warrant its own Class.

```
Class Conversation(models.Model):
  partner = models.CharField()
Class Weather_q(models.Model):
  #stuff
Class Health_q(models.Model):
  #stuff
Class Family_q(models.Model):
  #stuff
```

So let's say I want to have 2 conversations:

- Conversation 1 with Bob: ask two different weather questions and one question about his health
- Conversation 2 with Alice: ask about the weather and her family

Usually, I would code myself a normalization table for this:

```
INSERT INTO Conversation (partner) values ("Bob", "Alice"); --primary keys = 1 and 2
INSERT INTO NormalizationTable (fk_Conversation, fk_Weather_q, fk_Health_q,  fk_Family_q) VALUES 
  (1,1,0,0), -- Bob weather#1
  (1,2,0,0), -- Bob weather#2
  (1,0,1,0), -- Bob health#1
  (2,1,0,0), -- Alice weather#1
  (2,0,0,1); -- Alice family#1
```

Do I need to explicitly create this normalization table or is that discouraged?

```
Class NormalizationTable(models.Model):
  fk_Conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation)
  fk_Weather_q = models.ForeignKey(Weather)
  fk_Health_q = models.ForeignKey(Health)
  fk_Family_q = models.ForeignKey(Family)
```

Then I then wanted to execute the conversations. I wrote a view like this (skipping exception catching and logic to iterate through multiple questions per conversation):

```
from myapp.models import Conversation, Weather_q, Health_q, Family_q
def converse(request):
  #get this conversation's pk
  #assuming "mypartner" is provided by the URL dispatcher
  conversation = Conversation.objects.filter(partner=mypartner)[0]
  #get the relevant row of the NormalizationTable
  questions = NormalizationTable.objects.filter(fk_Conversation=conversation)[0]
  for question in questions:
    if question.fk_Weather_q:
      return render("weather.html", Weather_q.objects.filter(pk=fk_Weather_q)[0])
    if question.fk_Health_q:
      return render("health.html", Health_q.objects.filter(pk=fk_Health_q)[0])
    if question.fk_Family_q:
      return render("family.html", Family_q.objects.filter(pk=fk_Family_q)[0])
```

Considered holistically, is this the "Django" way to solve this kind of normalization problem (N objects associated with a container object)? Can I make better use of Django's inbuilt ORM or other tools?

Comment: Is "normalization table" a well known thing? I obviously know about database normalization, but this doesn't help me understand what "normalization table" is. Google is no help (it seems there are no real result with "normalization table" used as a term). Could you define what a "normalization table" is?

Comment: Don't use a "contrived example" that makes no sense. Come up with a better example that can be understood, but even then the answer will likely be "Write your models.py so the code makes sense, and don't worry about the normalisation."

Comment: @Ludwik Trammer I'm just using the term to describe a table with normalized data. People generally give them names that are meaningful for the data contained in them. I probably should have done this too.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, the example is actually more real than you think. See my comment to Kevin Christopher Henry's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside "normalization tables" (the term is unfamiliar to me), this is what I think is a "djangish" way of solving your problem. Please note that I went with your statement "each question is complicated enough to warrant its own Class". For me this means that every type of question necessitate its own unique fields and methods. Otherwise I would create a single `Question` model connected to a `Category` model by a `ForeignKey`.

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class Question(models.Model):
    # Fields and methods common to all kinds of questions
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
    label = models.CharField()  # example field


class WeatherQuestion(Question):
    # Fields and methods for weather questions only


class HealthQuestion(Question):
    # Fields and methods for health questions only


class FamilyQuestion(Question):
    # Fields and methods for family questions only
```

This way you would have a base `Question` model for all the fields and methods common to all questions, and a bunch of child models for describing different kinds of questions. There is an implicit relation between base model and its child models, maintained by Django. This gives you an ability to create a single queryset with different questions, no matter their type. Items in this queryset are of `Question` type by default, but can be converted to a particular question type by accessing a special attribute (for example a `healthquestion` attribute for `HealtQuestion`s). This is described in detail in the ["Multi-table model inheritance" section of Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).

Then in a view you can get a list of (different types of) questions and then detect their particular type:

```
from myapp.models import Question

def converse(request, partner_id):
    question = Question.objects.filter(partner=partner_id).first()

    # Detect question type
    question_type = "other"
    question_obj = question
    # in real life the list of types below would probably live in the settings
    for current_type in ['weather', 'health', 'family']:
        if hasattr(question, current_type + 'question'):
            question_type = current_type
            question_obj = getattr(question, current_type + 'question')
            break

    return render(
        "questions/{}.html".format(question_type),
        {'question': question_obj}
    )
```

The code for detecting question type is quite ugly and complicated. You could make it much simpler and more generic using the [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) from [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils) package. You would need to install the package and add the line to the `Question` model:

```
objects = InheritanceManager()
```

Then the view would then look something like this:

```
from myapp.models import Question

def converse(request, partner_id):
    question = Question.objects.filter(partner=partner_id).select_subclasses().first()
    question_type = question._meta.object_name.lower()

    return render(
        "questions/{}.html".format(question_type),
        {'question': question}
    )
```

Both views select only a single question - the first one. That's how the view in your example behaved, so I went with it. You could easily convert those examples to return a list of questions (of different types).

Comment: Thanks very much for introducing the `InheritanceManager`. That looks like what I need. I will go and read the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the term *normalization table*, but I see what you're trying to do.

What you've described is not, in my opinion, a very satisfactory way to model a database. The simplest approach would be to make all questions part of the same table, with a "type" field, and maybe some other optional fields that vary between the types. In that case, this becomes very simple in Django.

But, OK, you said "let's say... each question is complicated enough to warrant its own class." Django does have a solution for that, which is [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations). It would look something like this:

```
class ConversationQuestion(models.Model):
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    question_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    question = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'question_id')

# you can use prefetch_related("question") for efficiency
cqs = ConversationQuestion.objects.filter(conversation=conversation)
for cq in cqs:
    # do something with the question
    # you can look at the content_type if, as above, you need to choose
    # a separate template for each type.
    print(cq.question)
```

Because it's part of Django, you get some (but not total) support in terms of the admin, forms, etc.

Or you could do what you've done above, but, as you noticed, it's ugly and doesn't seem to capture the advantages of working with an ORM.

Comment: Thanks for accepting "each question is complicated enough to warrant its own class". I'm actually writing a quantitative market research app, and each question is structured very differently with unrelated fields ("Sort these 10 items in order of preference?", "What's missing from this shopping experience?", "Guess the price of this product?" etc). The note about `GenericForeignKey` is helpful - it allows me to think about just how much common content I can leverage into the ORM.